# turtlesim_node: cannot connect to X server

Tags: turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
turtlesim_node: cannot connect to X server
what is the problem?  help please

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201994/turtlesim_node:-cannot-connect-to-x-server/) by [Ainur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21513/ainur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like exactly the same question was asked, and got answered. http://answers.ros.org/question/55421/problem-with-ros-networking/

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0